# ViewController will only load once, app crashes when I go back then load it again

Tags: ios, objective-c

Objective C noob here. I'm linking from a UITableViewCell to a ViewController subclass. On my storyboard I have the UIViewController containing the UITableView as well as a custom class SubjectViewController with the identifier "Subject".

I also grab the text contained in the selected cell, add it to NSUserDefaults, and use that as the title of the Subject page.

When I launch the app, the first time I click on a UITableViewCell, the SubjectViewController launches perfectly. Any functionality I have on that page works fine. However when I go back to the home screen, then click on another UITableViewCell, the app freezes and I only get the message "11db".

Here are the two methods that are involved:

From ViewController.m

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    // Store cell label in NSUserDefaults to later display as the title
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString *cellID = cell.textLabel.text;

    [defaults setObject:cellID forKey:@"sceneTitle"];
    [defaults synchronize];

    //Present subjects view controller
    NSString * storyboardName = @"Main";
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle: nil];

    SubjectViewController * subject = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Subject"];
    [self presentViewController:subject animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

From SubjectViewController.m

```
- (IBAction)subjectBackPressed:(id)sender {
    NSString *storyboardName = @"Main";
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle: nil];

    NSString *home = @"Head and Neck";
    SubjectViewController * vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: home];
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Let me know if more code/ information would be helpful and I'll edit this post.

Comment: Hi, this is not how you present and dismiss a view controller. in the subjectBackPressed method just call [self dismissViewController:]. And have a look on how to pass data between view controllers in iOS (use segue etc)

Comment: Any specific resources that you think would be helpful? I'm having trouble understanding the Apple developer programming guide

Comment: Please see http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1 to learn how to debug a crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the vc1 was loaded from the main story board, no need to initialize again. Simply accessing self.storyboard will give the allocated instance of storyboard.

If you are presenting the vc2, it should be removed by dismissing it. Back action should be

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest either dismissing the current view with     self.dismissViewController or performing a segue back to the UIViewController